# What's the basis for the rumors that Macron takes cocaine?

Tags: russian-federation, france, drugs, propaganda

There's a French "observer" to the Russian election who [says](https://www.reddit.com/r/UkraineRussiaReport/comments/1bfdm74/ru_pov_i_saw_very_friendly_people_and_very_happy/)

> I think Macron and Zelensky take too much cocaine, and they should stop.

So, since the Zelensky angle [has been](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71640/why-did-putin-call-ukrainian-officials-drug-addicts) covered before here, what's the basis for the claim that Macron takes cocaine?

Comment: What makes you think the answer could be any different?

Comment: @BrianZ: did Macron take a public drug test, like Zelensky?

Comment: Why would Macron humiliate himself, and France, to answer to Russian agitprop?   
 Zelensky isn't in a situation where he can allow any doubts like that to get in the way of Ukraine aid - not at all the same circumstances.  Why bother asking this Q?

Comment: Macron seems unloved enough already, without having to speculate about his personal life

Comment: FYI, decades ago, in a presidential debate:  "Chirac:  Mr. President, can you tell me today's exchange rate to the Deutschmark?".  "Mitterand:  Sir, I am the President of France.  You are not my schoolmaster".  By and large, IIRC French public opinion agreed that Chirac had overreached himself by trying to ambush bad-on-economics Mitterand - who likely had no clue - and that he had infringed on the dignity of the president's office.  It would a major faux-pas for any head of state to stoop down to taking a drug test for such a ridiculous reason.

Answer (score 2):

Propaganda, of course. The enemy is depicted as weak and morally degraded. This does not need to have any grounding and most often does not.

Comment: At least we seem to know why we're getting this anti-Macron prop *right now* from that corner. Macron apparently turned hardline anti-Putin recently https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68575251